# Default to 'this display' when editing views

Tags: views

I am working on a display of a view I have. I want to make changes that apply only to the display that I'm working on; however the various editing widgets (relationships, filters, fields, etc) keep defaulting to apply to all displays. For the most part I remember to change it to "this display", but sometimes I don't, and I end up changing all displays.

Is there a way to change the default application to "this display"? Or have views remember which I chose?

Comment: Not that Im aware of, Im afraid this is the default behaviour. I often catch myself out by not selecting "This block override". :-(

Comment: Actually - Breaking the default behaviour for the very first display when you create a new view would mean that every new display you add would have its own settings for filters etc. You would just have to remember to do this everytime you add a view.

Comment: @Collins Since "No" seems to be the answer, can you post that as an answer? Then I will accept it : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that Im aware of, Im afraid this is the default behaviour. I often catch myself out by not selecting "This block override". :-(

But actually - Breaking the default behaviour for the very first display when you create a new view would mean that every new display you add would have its own settings for filters etc. You would just have to remember to do this everytime you add a view